# How to disable CollapsingToolbarLayout scrim color?

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need to prevent CollapsingToolbarLayout to hide its content after the user scrolls up the layout, is there a way to do this?

Setting app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent" doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 3):

You can use `app:statusBarScrim="@color/transparent"` in your xml.
This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this lines

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ...
  (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbarLayout).setContentScrim(null);
  (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsingToolbarLayout).setStatusBarScrim(null);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it in this way:

```
app:contentScrim="@null"
app:statusBarScrim="@null"
```